# how can i remove the underline of class in IDEA console

Tags: intellij-idea, console

[image: the console output]

[image: color shecme settings]

IDEA 2024.1(EAP) 241.12662.62

Change the "Color Scheme => Hyperlinks" settings dosn't work (restarted IDEA).

Comment: The highlighting could be coming from a custom plugin. Does it make a difference if you disable all of the non-bundled plugins and restart the IDE? -> File | Settings | Plugins | ⚙ | Disable all downloaded plugins

Comment: @Koyasha Only installed two downloaded plugins. Disable them not working.

Comment: [Solved by JetBerains Community](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/17113768008594/comments/17177976805394)